# How to handle MYSQL NOW() in different timezones?

Tags: php, mysql, timezone

I am using PHP and MySQL. I have following insert query which is working fine.

```
$query="INSERT INTO mytable (user_id, user_datetime) VALUES ".
       "(".$_SESSION["user_id"].", NOW());";
```

Problem is that:

1) When I was testing on my localhost, NOW() was picking date and time from my system. That was good, no problem!!!

2) Now I have hosted my site to a web hosting server which is anywhere in Canada and I am in India. Now if any insert is happening, it is storing the time of Canada not of India. This is the problem. How can I get rid of this. How do I save Indian time in my database?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/930900/how-to-set-timezone-of-mysql

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two solutions: use the PHP approach or the MySQL approach. (your question title is misleading, it's not a `PHP NOW()` but a `MySQL NOW()`).

With PHP, you can use the [`date_default_timezone_set`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) function for this.
It will set the default timezone for your PHP script.

Just remember to put it near the top so it applied to what you are doing.

**BUT** this will set the timezone for all PHP function, not your MySQL database `NOW()` command.

To modify the timezone of MySQL, you have to use `SET time_zone = timezonename;`. See [this SO thread for setting MySQL timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930900/how-to-set-timezone-of-mysql) or the [official documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/time-zone-support.html).

Example:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');
$query = "INSERT INTO mytable (user_id, user_datetime) VALUES ".
   "(".$_SESSION["user_id"].", ".date('Y-m-d H:i:s').");";

// OR

$query = "SET time_zone = 'Asia/Calcutta';"; // this will persist only for the current connection
$query .= "INSERT INTO mytable (user_id, user_datetime) VALUES ".
           "(".$_SESSION["user_id"].", NOW());";
```

Comment: what is timezonename here in statement SET time_zone = timezonename;?

Comment: There are several formats available: 'SYSTEM' or an offset from UTC like '+10:00' or 'Asia/Calcutta'.

Answer (score 0):

This is a really old thread, but I would still like to add my five cents here, which, truly, are missing. Typically, you wouldn't want to store any local datetime in the database, you want to store **UTC** datetime and later convert it to whatever timezone using PHP's `DateTimeZone` class, particularly if this is a public project. To achieve that you must use `UTC_TIMESTAMP()` instead of `NOW()` or its equivalent `LOCALTIME()`, there is absolutely no need to modify MySQL timezone parameter. And even if there aren't any users but yourself, storing timestamps in UTC format is just a standard and better practice.